# Question about length of degree $n$ submodule of the quotient of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, commutative-algebra

This is from Matsumura's commutative ring theory p.96.

> Example 2. Let $k$ be a field, and $F\left(X_{0}, \ldots, X_{r}\right)$ a homogeneous polynomial of degree $s$; set $R=k\left[X_{0}, \ldots, X_{r}\right] /(F(X))$. Then for $n \geqslant s$
> $$
> l\left(R_{n}\right)=\binom{n+r}{r}-\binom{n-s+r}{r}
> $$

Could you explain why the above equation hold? I know that $\binom{n+r}{r}$ is came from the numbest of $n$-monomials. However, I don't know why the relationship induced by $F(X)$ let us get rid of the number of $(n-s)$-monomials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modding out by $F$ means that we kill the subspace of $R_n$ that is obtained as the image of the multiplication map $R_{n-s} \overset{\cdot F}\to R_n$ (at least when $n \ge s$; otherwise the map doesn't exist and there's nothing in the kernel). This map is injective, so you're just subtracting the rank of $R_{n-s}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!